# Categorical Variables (Y or N) in KNN Classification?

Tags: machine-learning, python, scikit-learn, k-nn

Practicing KNN and I just had a query about pre-processing, as I understand KNN doesn't work with categorical features.

I've read into one-hot-encoding (dummy variables) which I suppose if I applied to the below dataset, would essentially double the amount of columns I have.

However, is this required. Would it work to simply replace y with 0, and n with 1 across the whole dataset?

```
target     Q1     Q2     Q3  
Wealthy     y      y      y         
Wealthy     n      y      y          
Poor        y      y      y   
Poor        n      y      n          
Poor        y      y      y
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to apply machine learning, all data must be represented as numbers. The n/y should be replaced with 0/1.

k-nearest neighbors algorithm (k-NN) requires a distance metric. One option is to use Hamming distance with booleans values (0/1).

Comment: Thanks. So would just replacing them with 0/1 be known as binary encoding, and is there a reason I'd use this over one-hot encoding?